# flexslider not showing images

Tags: javascript, html, css

hi i am running simple flexslider. all images,css and js files are loaded however images does not shows in my case. I tries and googled many times but i did not get exact problem please help here is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='file:///C:/Users/suku/Desktop/code/flexslider/css/flexslider.css' class='flexslider' media='all' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src='file:///C:/Users/suku/Desktop/code/flexslider/js/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
        <script src='file:///C:/Users/suku/Desktop/code/flexslider/js/jquery.flexslider.js'>   </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(window).load(function() {
                    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                        animation: "slide"
                    });
                });
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                        <img alt='slider01' src='file:///C:/Users/suku/Desktop/code/flexslider/images/1.jpg'>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img alt='slider02' src='file:///C:/Users/suku/Desktop/code/flexslider/images/2.jpg'>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- end flexslider -->

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you able to replicate this issue in www.jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I think your problem in about your custome css , if you have a custome style , check direction of your slider . you take it direction : ltr ;

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the src values as required. Just bring images to the same folder where your html file resides and use  . I think you are new to this field. I don't know whether your flexslider is working or not but you will also have to move that too to the same folder. Merry Christmas Suku

Answer (score 0):

You are using window load() within ready().
The load() function will not be executed unless every resource is loaded to the document, while ready() will execute when all the DOMs are prepared.

Please use $(window).load() outside  $(document).ready()

Comment: I think there is no need to use both. Either use `ready` or `load`

Answer (score 0):

Put that images into your project and then use path like

```
src="~/Content/Images/slide1.jpg"
```

and use

```
$(window).resize(function () {

    var slider1 = $('.flexslider').flexslider({

        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: false,
        itemWidth: 150,
        controlNav: false,
        touch: true,
        keyboard: true,
        minItems: 2,
        slideshow: false,
        itemMargin: 5
    });
});
```